# Read SQL encrypted columns in Azure Data Flow

Tags: sql, azure-data-factory, encryption-symmetric

I have few encrypted columns in a table in Azure Synapse Analytics database and I want to read these columns in a decrypted mode in Azure Data Flow. How is that possible?

I was able to decrypt the column and read it in SSMS, using below example:

```
SELECT
    CAST(decryptbykey([Encrypted Number]) as nvarchar(254))  'Decrypted Number'
FROM ITO.Table1
```

But I am unable to run same query in Azure Data Flow. I was not able to find any guidance from MS yet.

If I read the encrypted column in Azure Data Flow, it look like:

[image]

If I try to get the decrypted data using a SP, it is getting failed on Data Previewed tab. Below my Data Flow settings:
[image]
*Error:*
[image]
Note: to encrypt the data, I followed [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/encrypt-a-column-of-data?view=azure-sqldw-latest#encrypt-with-simple-symmetric-encryption) by MS

Comment: How you usually do the decryption? like sort of wrapping it with some stored procedures? Would it be helpful to you if you call the stored procedure in ADF, and let the stored procedure to do its work?

Answer (score 0):

in order to read your encrypted column, you need to decrypt it.
Since you followed MS docs, this is what you need to do :

> -- First, open the symmetric key with which to decrypt the data.
> OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY SSN_Key_01
> DECRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE HumanResources037;
> GO

and after it you should decrypt your data as written here :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/encrypt-a-column-of-data?view=azure-sqldw-latest#encrypt-with-simple-symmetric-encryption

this is my approach for your usecase :
i encrypted a column using symmetric keys as written in MS docs.
and used **Sample** data as my data in SQL DB.

1. create a stored procedure in SSMS like so :

   SET ANSI_NULLS ON
   GO
   SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
   GO
   CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[open_symmetric_key_and_decrypt_data]
   AS BEGIN
   OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY SSN_Key_10   DECRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE CustomerDetails;
   select EncryptedID,CONVERT(varchar, DecryptByKey(EncryptedID)) as decryptedId
   from SalesLT.Customer
   END
   GO
2. save the stored procedure and run it in SSMS just to make sure it works properly
3. in ADF , created a new Data flow, in Source :
   [image]
4. loaded the data by using stored procedure.
5. [image: List item]
6. in data preview tab click on Map drifted (it should open to you a new tab like so ), basicly here we are mapping the drifted column as a new column to our data so you can use it in another activities.**Dont forget to delete it before you write to your sink**  [image]

and now you can do whatever you want with your decrypted column.

**check these links out:**
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-data-flow-schema-drift

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/stored-procedures/create-a-stored-procedure?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: unfortunately that is not working with me. The SP works in SSMS, but in ADF, when I choose the option in data source as sp then try to run 'Data Preview' I get below error: shaded.msdataflow.com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: 111212;Operation cannot be performed within a transaction.
Also, in the derived column, I can't see the new column that supposed to be retrieved by the sp.

Comment: did you enable "Schema Drift" option in the data source? if not it will not work since we are adding drifted column. 
Please enable everything as described above

Comment: share your DataFlow if you can ..

Comment: I have added the screenshot to the main question.

Comment: please take a look here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-troubleshoot-connector-format 
i can see the same error that you're having

Comment: I did, my connector is pointing to Synapse already. I noticed in your answer you used Azure SQL Database, but my case is related to Synapse. There could be some limitation in Synapse as column-level encryption is just recently released. Will check with MS about this.